# Spark Dataframe With for Loop: Optimization Technique

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I trying to implement blow logic.

```
    1. Taking some records from one table.
    2. based on resultant data I'm using one loop.
    3.then inside loop taking data from other tables in two different dataframe
    4. joining these two dataframes and loading data into 3rd table.

    var id_chck1 = s"select distinct id ,id1, id2  from table  WHERE type =  'N';
    val id_chck = hive.executeQuery(id_chck1)
    for (data <- id_chck) {

   var id = data(0)
    var id1 = data(1)
    var id2 = data(2)

      val values_1 = "select distinct bill, bil_num, id_num,  bill_date,process_date from table l WHERE id2 = '222';
      val values_1_data = hive.executeQuery(values_1)
      for (row <- values_1_data.collect) {
        val bill = row.mkString(",").split(",")(0)
        val bil_num = row.mkString(",").split(",")(1)
        val id_num= row.mkString(",").split(",")(2)
        val bill_date = row.mkString(",").split(",")(3)

        var df1 = s"select column name from tablename where id=222"
        val df1_data = hive.executeQuery(df1)
        var df2 = s"s"select column name from tablename2 where id=222""
        val df2_data = hive.executeQuery(df2)

      val df3="joining df1 and df2"
        df3.write.format("orc").mode("Append").save("hdfslocation")
      }
      var load1 = s"load data inpath 'hdfslocation' into table tablename"
      val load1_data = hive.executeUpdate(load1)
```

but this process is taking 6+ hrs is there any other way to doing the same thing so it can complete in short time.is there any other way to do the same thing..like rdd or setting some spark hive properties to improve performance.
I have 5,00,000 records in test1 table.

Comment: Can you clearly mention what is someconditions ? .. first of all you are collecting first dataframe & looping .. this step is wrong .. can you add complete code ?

Comment: instead of for loop .. you can get same result using joins - a1, df1, df2 .. most of your logic is executing by only driver & you are not using spark benefits..

Comment: @Srinivas  I have updated the question with sample code. Please read hive as hiveContext.

Comment: @Srinivas  yes srinivas I'm new to spark mostly used spark with sql.so not aware about much of spark benefits and data frame methods.

Comment: ok, got it.. which version of spark are you using & hdp version ?

Comment: I'm using spark 2.1 @Srinivas

Comment: one question, where you have used id, id1, & id2 values ?

Comment: @Srinivas val values_1 = "select distinct bill, bil_num, id_num,  bill_date,process_date from table l WHERE id2 = '222'; while select data for values_1 df I have used all these 3 ids i have added one here but in real code used all the 3 ids.

Comment: val values_1 = "select distinct bill, bil_num, id_num, bill_date,process_date from table l WHERE id2 =${id2} and  id =${id} and and  id1 =${id1}  Like this @Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

could you please add the input and expected output as an example? 
it's hard to see what exactly you're trying to achieve

Comment: Hi @zakukaZ i have implemented same thing using inner join.